# JavaScript - Code after case in switch statements

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to decipher [this code](https://github.com/garycourt/murmurhash-js/blob/master/murmurhash3_gc.js) (MurmurHash) and came across the following lines:

```
switch (remainder) {
    case 3: k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i + 2) & 0xff) << 16;
    case 2: k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xff) << 8;
    case 1: k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
    
    // When is this executed?

    k1 = (((k1 & 0xffff) * c1) + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c1) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    k1 = (k1 << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);
    k1 = (((k1 & 0xffff) * c2) + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c2) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    h1 ^= k1;
}
```

My question is as follows: I have never seen code inside a switch statement that is not part of either a `case` or a `default` and would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain when the part after the last `case` statement is supposed to get executed.

Is it an alternative way of writing a `default` statement?
Or will this always get executed, just as if it were written outside of the `switch` block?

Information on this topic seems very difficult to come by as documentation on `switch` statements generally deals with `case` and `default`, and it's also impossible to test without changing the code too much which might affect its behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Case 3 falls through to 2 and 1, and case 2 falls through to case 1. Each subsequent case piggy-backs off the previous. Notice there are no `break` statements? The formatting, combined with the use of bit-wize operations is intended to throw you off on purpose.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I see, thank you. So the last part (after the last case) also gets executed if one of the cases match and never if there is not match?

Comment: The last 4 lines always execute, if the remainder is 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is part of `case 1`.

Personally I'd re-arrange the whitespace to be more clear:

```
switch (remainder) {
  case 3:
    k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i + 2) & 0xff) << 16;
  case 2:
    k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i + 1) & 0xff) << 8;
  case 1:
    k1 ^= (key.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff);
    k1 = (((k1 & 0xffff) * c1) + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c1) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    k1 = (k1 << 15) | (k1 >>> 17);
    k1 = (((k1 & 0xffff) * c2) + ((((k1 >>> 16) * c2) & 0xffff) << 16)) & 0xffffffff;
    h1 ^= k1;
}
```

The point is that, without a `break;` in any of the cases, any matched case will execute and then control will flow to the next case.

So, assuming `remainder` can *only* be `1`, `2`, or `3`...

- If it's `3`, all statements are executed.
- If it's `2`, `case 3` is skipped but the rest is executed.
- If it's `1`, `case 3` and `case 2` are skipped but the rest is executed.

The logic is, perhaps a bit unintuitively, relying on the control flow of `switch` to continue on to the next (not-actually-matching) `case`.

Comment: I see, it was the whitespace that confused me, it's really simple actually. Thank you so much!